# Generating synthetic data based off existing real data (in Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, statistics, data

I am looking for an approach to **generate synthetic data for anomaly detection**. We have real data, but want to **inject anomalies** to battle-test the model (the real data is too limited for likely future anomalies).

I would like to **mimic the statistical properties** of the real data, such as **mean**, **mode**, **standard deviation**, etc., to create the synthetic data, then inject anomalies based off reasonable extreme values (if we know the statistical properties of each column in the real data then we can deduce what an extreme value might look like for that column).

Are there any Python packages that generate synthetic data based off known statistical properties in real data. I imagine this is similar to differential privacy, but we are not doing this to protect privacy and don't need an overkill method.

[scikit-learn](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/09/scikit-learn-synthetic-dataset.html) can generate synthetic data but it doesn't seem to have a method to base it off of existing real data statistical properties.

I can do something simple like this:

```
res = {}
for column in df: 
    nrows = len(df[column].index)
    mean = df[column].mean()
    std = df[column].std()
    mu, sigma = mean, std # mean and standard deviation
    synthetic_data = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, nrows)
    res[column] = synthetic_data
```

...which just detects the means and standard deviation of each column then recreates it using a numpy draw from a normal distribution (big assumption), but obviously this doesn't mock the data well:

**Real Data**

[image]

**Synthetic Data**

[image]

Comment: It is not 100% clear what you call an anomaly in your graph : the spike at 1400 ? the absence of value before it ? other spikes ? a signal that is not observed yet ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is the Python package imblearn which contains the [SMOTE algorithm](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html). SMOTE generates synthetic samples from a real dataset by interpolating plausible new datapoints based on observed data.